# Turn on full backtrace in Ruby on Rails TestCase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing

Only one line of backtrace is displayed when I run:

```
rake test
```

Output:

...

```
ERROR should get search for keywords (1.93s) 
  NoMethodError: undefined method `features' for #<Transcript:0x00000006243780>
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.1.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:385:in `method_missing'
```

...

I need more lines of backtrack information.
I have tried

- rake test --trace
- `Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers!` in config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
- setting global $DEBUG=true

and it didn't work.

How can I turn it on?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
BACKTRACE=blegga rake test

BACKTRACE=blegga rails test # rails 5+
```

Append `--trace` if you need rake related log.

Comment: That looks like such a random thing to add, but it works!  Where's the official documentation on that?

Comment: For those seeing this in future and wondering if they actually have to use the string "blegga", no, you can also do something like `BACKTRACE=1` :)

Comment: @pnomolos thank you for clarifying, this is such a confusing answer; I was googling `blegga` to see what it meant.

Answer (score 6):

Nowdays you can run:

```
rails test --backtrace
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured this out. The issue is with the 'turn' gem included in Rails 3.1, or actually with turn v0.8.2, which is required by the default Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', '0.8.2', require: false
end
```

Turn v0.8.2 doesn't include the full backtrace, so you have to upgrade to get it. I did that by changing the above in my Gemfile to this:

```
group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', require: false
  gem 'minitest'
end
```

(I had to add minitest because otherwise turn throws a RuntimeError saying "MiniTest v1.6.0 is out of date.")

Then I ran `bundle update turn` and got the latest verion (0.9.2 as of this writing). That gives full backtraces.