# No backtrace in views in rails testing mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, backtrace

I run some cucumber/capybara integration tests and use capybara-screenshot to retrieve screenshots when something fails.

However, if there is an error in a view, i dont see any backtrace, f.ex:

```
Internal Server Error
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2013-06-27) at 127.0.0.1:55711
```

I see proper full backtrace in development mode, but not in testing mode.

Cucumber error message is just "link not found". Cucumber step is simply:

```
click_link('My Link')
```

Comment: Isn't it similar to [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7633839/2291093)?

Comment: no, i don't have 'turn' gem anywhere, and my problem is that theres no backtrace in a view, it outputs perfectly well in shell.
i don't even have a line number to check where error happens as opposed to example in given question.