# Rails - Testing fixtures error NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, associations, fixtures

I have a problem running tests that use fixtures with associations between models.

Here's the error I get, as soon as I run `rake test`:

```
ERROR["test_truth", SevenPortfolioTest, 0.005154775]
 test_truth#SevenPortfolioTest (0.01s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass


ERROR["test_should_destroy_item_video", SevenPortfolio::ItemVideosControllerTest, 0.008887804]
 test_should_destroy_item_video#SevenPortfolio::ItemVideosControllerTest (0.01s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass


ERROR["test_should_get_index", SevenPortfolio::ItemVideosControllerTest, 0.011364416]
 test_should_get_index#SevenPortfolio::ItemVideosControllerTest (0.01s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass


ERROR["test_should_create_item_video", SevenPortfolio::ItemVideosControllerTest, 0.014584266]
 test_should_create_item_video#SevenPortfolio::ItemVideosControllerTest (0.01s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass


ERROR["test_should_get_new", SevenPortfolio::ItemVideosControllerTest, 0.017282812]
 test_should_get_new#SevenPortfolio::ItemVideosControllerTest (0.02s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass


ERROR["test_should_update_item_video", SevenPortfolio::ItemVideosControllerTest, 0.019729858]
 test_should_update_item_video#SevenPortfolio::ItemVideosControllerTest (0.02s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass


ERROR["test_should_get_edit", SevenPortfolio::ItemVideosControllerTest, 0.022365633]
 test_should_get_edit#SevenPortfolio::ItemVideosControllerTest (0.02s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass


ERROR["test_should_destroy_item", SevenPortfolio::ItemsControllerTest, 0.025860205]
 test_should_destroy_item#SevenPortfolio::ItemsControllerTest (0.03s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass


ERROR["test_should_get_edit", SevenPortfolio::ItemsControllerTest, 0.030867796]
 test_should_get_edit#SevenPortfolio::ItemsControllerTest (0.03s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass


ERROR["test_should_show_item", SevenPortfolio::ItemsControllerTest, 0.036687105]
 test_should_show_item#SevenPortfolio::ItemsControllerTest (0.04s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass


ERROR["test_should_update_item", SevenPortfolio::ItemsControllerTest, 0.040130774]
 test_should_update_item#SevenPortfolio::ItemsControllerTest (0.04s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass


ERROR["test_should_create_item_with_video", SevenPortfolio::ItemsControllerTest, 0.042776553]
 test_should_create_item_with_video#SevenPortfolio::ItemsControllerTest (0.04s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass


ERROR["test_should_get_index", SevenPortfolio::ItemsControllerTest, 0.045301694]
 test_should_get_index#SevenPortfolio::ItemsControllerTest (0.05s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass


ERROR["test_should_get_new", SevenPortfolio::ItemsControllerTest, 0.048094189]
 test_should_get_new#SevenPortfolio::ItemsControllerTest (0.05s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass


ERROR["test_should_create_item_with_gallery", SevenPortfolio::ItemsControllerTest, 0.051019403]
 test_should_create_item_with_gallery#SevenPortfolio::ItemsControllerTest (0.05s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm testing a rails engine. Here's my fixtures:

```
# test/fixtures/seven_portfolio/items.yml
item_one:
  description: item one description
  finished_at: <%= 7.days.ago %>
  is_featured: true
  item_type: 0

item_two:
  description: item two description
  finished_at: <%= 6.days.ago %>
  is_featured: false
  item_type: 1


# test/fixtures/seven_gallery/galleries.yml
gallery_one:
  title: seven_gallery_gallery_one_title
  item: item_one

# test/fixtures/seven_gallery/photos.yml
photo_one:
  caption: photo_one_caption
  gallery: gallery_one

# test/fixtures/seven_portfolio/item_videos.yml
one:
  item: item_one
```

When, for example, I remove `item: item_one` and similar associations lines. The test works well.

--
**EDIT**

Here's the backtrace

```
Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib:lib:test"  "/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/**/*_test.rb" ]

/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/testtask.rb:108:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils.rb:57:in `call'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils.rb:57:in `sh'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils.rb:96:in `ruby'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `ruby'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/testtask.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:58:in `verbose'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/testtask.rb:100:in `block in define'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
```

---

**EDIT**

Here's `Item` class:

```
module SevenPortfolio
  class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :item_video, class_name:'SevenPortfolio::ItemVideo', foreign_key: "seven_portfolio_item_id"
    has_one :item_gallery, class_name: 'SevenGallery::Gallery', foreign_key: "seven_portfolio_item_id"
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_video, :item_gallery

    before_save :process_type

    def process_type
      self.build_item_video if self.item_type == 0
      self.build_item_gallery if self.item_type == 1
    end

    def type_content
      self.item_gallery if self.item_type == 0
      self.item_video if self.item_type == 1
    end
  end
end
```

And `Gallery` class:

```
class SevenGallery::Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SevenGallery::Concerns::Gallery
  belongs_to :item, :class_name => 'SevenPortfolio::Item'
end
```

---

**EDIT**
Here's the `schema.rb` file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150414145951) do

  create_table "seven_gallery_galleries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title",                   limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.integer  "seven_portfolio_item_id", limit: 4
  end

  add_index "seven_gallery_galleries", ["seven_portfolio_item_id"], name: "index_seven_gallery_galleries_on_seven_portfolio_item_id", using: :btree

  create_table "seven_gallery_photos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "caption",                  limit: 255
    t.string   "image",                    limit: 255
    t.integer  "seven_gallery_gallery_id", limit: 4
    t.datetime "created_at",                                             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                             null: false
    t.boolean  "is_new",                   limit: 1,     default: true
    t.boolean  "is_featured",              limit: 1,     default: false
    t.text     "description",              limit: 65535
    t.string   "alt",                      limit: 255
    t.integer  "position",                 limit: 4,     default: 0
  end

  add_index "seven_gallery_photos", ["seven_gallery_gallery_id"], name: "index_seven_gallery_photos_on_seven_gallery_gallery_id", using: :btree

  create_table "seven_portfolio_item_videos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "url",                     limit: 255
    t.text     "description",             limit: 65535
    t.string   "title",                   limit: 255
    t.integer  "seven_portfolio_item_id", limit: 4
    t.datetime "created_at",                            null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                            null: false
  end

  add_index "seven_portfolio_item_videos", ["seven_portfolio_item_id"], name: "index_seven_portfolio_item_videos_on_seven_portfolio_item_id", using: :btree

  create_table "seven_portfolio_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",                                null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                null: false
    t.text     "description", limit: 65535
    t.date     "finished_at"
    t.boolean  "is_featured", limit: 1,     default: false
    t.integer  "item_type",   limit: 4,     default: 0
  end

  add_foreign_key "seven_gallery_galleries", "seven_portfolio_items", on_delete: :cascade
  add_foreign_key "seven_gallery_photos", "seven_gallery_galleries", on_delete: :cascade
  add_foreign_key "seven_portfolio_item_videos", "seven_portfolio_items", on_delete: :cascade
end
```

Comment: Where does this error point to?

Comment: @MarekLipka Sorry, can you clarify more?

Comment: This is Ruby error, it has backtrace. I'd like to see this backtrace.

Comment: @MarekLipka I've edited the question with the backtrace. Thanks.

Comment: You define `item_one` to just be an empty hash. Are you sure that makes sense? Can you please post you `Item` class. How is the association between an gallery and an item defined?

Comment: @spickermann Would you mind telling me what empty hash means ? is it empty data ? I've posted `item` and `gallery` classes at the end of the question. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this line `item_one: {}` means that the fixture would try to create an item like this `Item.new({})`, without any arguments. IMO that does not make much sense. Did you read the [Rails Guide about testing and fictures](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures)?

Comment: @spickermann Well, I've rewritten the fixtures with the one edited in my question. Added some data. But unfortunately the issue still occurs.

Comment: @RafaelAdel: I'm at work now, and cannot reprodruce your environment here, but it looks to me that there is an initialization error when the item gets constructed without prior being an video or gallery. But I think you should have a look at polymorphic associations and avoid having all the manual work with item_type (and the whole Item class) alltogether. See http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/understanding-polymorphic-associations-in-rails

Comment: @RafaelAdel can you provide more info about your db schema? Are there any STI relations between your app models?

Comment: @IoannisTziligkakis I've edited the question with the `schema.rb` file. And no, I don't have STI relations in my models.

Comment: @JörgReichardt I can't get my head around imlpementing polymorphic associations in my models. Would you mind suggesting how to do it?

Comment: @RafaelAdel: My mistake, I got it backwards. Polymorphic Associations won't help here.

Answer (score 10):

I've hit the same errors after migrating and rolling back a few times in my dev environment. It's something to do with the "_type" column.

The only thing that fixed it for me was a drop/create of the test database:

```
bundle exec rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=test
```

Be confident your `schema.rb` is in good shape before doing this.

Answer (score 3):

This error happen when in you model you create a relationship that doesnt have a field in the db. Example:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to account
end
```

But in your table contacts:

```
create_table "contacts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "fname"
    t.string   "lname"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
    t.boolean  "primary"
    t.integer  "contactable_id"
    t.integer  "contactable_type"
  end
```

See there's no account_id field.

In my case I forgot to update the model's `belongs_to` to be polymorphic:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contactable, polymorphic: true
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts, as: :contactable
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this not a duplicate/similar problem to this issue?

[Loading Rails Fixtures in a Specific Order when Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046415/loading-rails-fixtures-in-a-specific-order-when-testing)

What could be happening is your fixtures are not being loaded in the correct order so when item is referenced it comes up as nil.

From the response of the other answer you can try

Here's how you fix your issue:

1. Log into Postgresql with your default superuser (mine is "postgres")
   Perform the following command:
2. ALTER ROLE yourtestdbuser WITH SUPERUSER;
3. Enjoy your properly working fixtures.

If you are using mysql it is probably similar issue.

Comment: But I'm logged to mysql as `root` user

Comment: Could you maybe add one of your tests to your question? Everywhere in your question you have the attribute `type` when it looks like it should be `item_type`. Thanks.

Comment: I have the `root` user account connected to the app. So I think it's already a superuser.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: People are landing on this question for different reasons. My problem/solution is described in 'Fixing the error'. I hope this extended explanation will help you learn why you're experiencing this cryptic error, and save you some time debugging it.

### How to diagnose this issue

I had almost the same error when running my tests: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass`, or `NoMethodError: undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`. There were no line numbers to reference, and [Lucas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30836605/1038034) of rebuilding would *sometimes* work and then would stop working; I'd later learn this is because of caching and loading order of fixture files.

#### Finding where the error is thrown

My error was with how my fixtures were setup. I found this by running my tests with a full backtrace described in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8812140/1038034):

```
BACKTRACE=YES rake test test/controllers/document_submissions_controller_test.rb
```

This pointed to the gem files in ActiveSupport that were throwing the error. Here's my full log for a single test:

[image]

So it seems the error is in loading my fixtures, since the error is originating in `active_record/fixtures.rb:758` (see highlighted line above). However, I have a large amount of fixtures in my app, I needed to narrow down which in particular was causing the problem.

#### Setting a break point

I opened the `active_record/fixtures.rb:758` file in my code editor using the command below:

```
code /Users/mattmcinnis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb
```

*Note: I'm using VSCode with the `code` command, but any code editor will do.*

On line 758 where the error occurs, I saw this code:

```
FixtureSet::File.open(file) do |fh|
  fh.each do |fixture_name, row|  # line 758
    fixtures[fixture_name] = ActiveRecord::Fixture.new(row, model_class)
  end 
end
```

..which I wrapped in a rescue block, and modified to:

```
FixtureSet::File.open(file) do |fh|
  begin
    fh.each do |fixture_name, row|
      fixtures[fixture_name] = ActiveRecord::Fixture.new(row, model_class)
    end
  rescue
    debugger
  end
end
```

*NOTE: Be sure to revert any changes to this file when you're done!*

#### Finding the problem file

I'm interested in which file, captured in the loop above in the variable `fh`, was causing the error. Running my test suite again I hit my breakpoint and found the filename that was causing the problem:

```
> (byebug) fh
  => ... @file="permissions.yml"
```

#### Fixing the error

In my `permissions.yml` file, my fixture is referring to a related model by hard coding the 'id' in, instead of referring by name:

Ex. `permissions.yml`

```
permission1:
  ...
  user_id: <%= User.first.id %>  # Bad!
```

Fixing the last line to something like, `user: user1` to refer to the `user1` fixture in `users.yml` solved the issue.

Hope this helps someone. I lost half a day on this one, and found it super hard to diagnose.