# NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I'm new to rails. I'm facing an issue regarding test cases using minitest. When I'm trying to run the test cases throwing me bunch of errors in each test cases. I guess fixtures not loading correctly. I'm looking for immediate response. Thankyou.
**Errors mentioned below**

```
    1) Error:
CompanyTest#test_fixtures_loaded_and_valid:
NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass
    activerecord (4.2.11.3) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:662:in `block (2 levels) in table_rows'
    activerecord (4.2.11.3) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:650:in `each_value'
    activerecord (4.2.11.3) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:650:in `block in table_rows'
    activerecord (4.2.11.3) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:621:in `each'
    activerecord (4.2.11.3) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:621:in `map'
    activerecord (4.2.11.3) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:621:in `table_rows'
    activerecord (4.2.11.3) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:526:in `block (3 levels) in create_fixtures'
    activerecord (4.2.11.3) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:524:in `each'
    activerecord (4.2.11.3) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:524:in `block (2 levels) in create_fixtures'
    activerecord (4.2.11.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
    activerecord (4.2.11.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
    activerecord (4.2.11.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
    activerecord (4.2.11.3) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:523:in `block in create_fixtures'
    activerecord (4.2.11.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:300:in `disable_referential_integrity'
    activerecord (4.2.11.3) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:508:in `create_fixtures'
    activerecord (4.2.11.3) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:979:in `load_fixtures'
    activerecord (4.2.11.3) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:941:in `setup_fixtures'
    activerecord (4.2.11.3) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:826:in `before_setup'
    minitest (5.14.2) lib/minitest/test.rb:96:in `block (3 levels) in run'
    minitest (5.14.2) lib/minitest/test.rb:195:in `capture_exceptions'
    minitest (5.14.2) lib/minitest/test.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    minitest (5.14.2) lib/minitest.rb:272:in `time_it'
    minitest (5.14.2) lib/minitest/test.rb:94:in `block in run'
    minitest (5.14.2) lib/minitest.rb:367:in `on_signal'
    minitest (5.14.2) lib/minitest/test.rb:211:in `with_info_handler'
    minitest (5.14.2) lib/minitest/test.rb:93:in `run'
    minitest (5.14.2) lib/minitest.rb:1029:in `run_one_method'
    minitest (5.14.2) lib/minitest.rb:341:in `run_one_method'
    minitest (5.14.2) lib/minitest.rb:328:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    minitest (5.14.2) lib/minitest.rb:327:in `each'
    minitest (5.14.2) lib/minitest.rb:327:in `block in run'
    minitest (5.14.2) lib/minitest.rb:367:in `on_signal'
    minitest (5.14.2) lib/minitest.rb:354:in `with_info_handler'
    minitest (5.14.2) lib/minitest.rb:326:in `run'
    minitest (5.14.2) lib/minitest.rb:164:in `block in __run'
    minitest (5.14.2) lib/minitest.rb:164:in `map'
    minitest (5.14.2) lib/minitest.rb:164:in `__run'
    minitest (5.14.2) lib/minitest.rb:141:in `run'
    minitest (5.14.2) lib/minitest.rb:68:in `block in autorun'
```

**company_test**

````
class CompanyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'fixtures loaded and valid' do
    Company.all.each do |company|
      assert company.valid?
    end
  end
end ```

**test/fixtures/companies.yml**
```generic:
  name: Generic
  slug: generic

trump:
  name: Trump
  slug: trump
````

** bundle exec rake test test/models/company_test.rb**

Comment: Can you post the contents of `CompanyTest#test_abc`?
And maybe the fixtures related to it if you can?

Comment: Could you edit the original question to include that information? If nothing else but for the superior formatting.

Comment: It is likely one of your other fixtures has an issue. Temporarily comment out (or otherwise remove) every fixture except the one you're trying to work with. Then see if those tests run. If so, then bring back your fixtures until you find the one with the issue.

Comment: Also, it's best not to assign IDs in your fixtures, so remove those once you're comfortable.

Comment: @BenFenner
I tried what you said, but this one not working too.

Comment: @BenFenner
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the contents of your test and fixture. Fixtures rely on whitespace formatting, and that is impossible to determine with the way comments work.

Comment: @BenFenner please, see now.

Comment: I think you should look through the answers here, especially this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56924732/14837782

Comment: @BenFenner
I tried but not working for me.

Comment: What happens when you run that test with that fixture file completely empty/blank?

Comment: @BenFenner
If i try to run test with completely empty fixture file, still throwing the same errors mentioned in question.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is in another fixture then. You should comment out, or temporarily delete, all of the other fixtures and then try the test again.

Comment: @BenFenner So. yes it works. I comment out all the fixtures and test a specific one works fine. But now the problem is, how should i find out that specific which is not allowing any test to run as there exits bunch of fixtures around one hundred above.

Comment: You might have to do a binary search to figure out which fixture is the problem.
Go ahead and restore half of the fixtures and then run the test again. If it works, then restore half of the remaining fixtures and keep repeating until you get the error again. Then you'll have an idea of which fixture contains the problem. Keep restoring them in chunks until you find the problematic one.

Comment: @BenFenner 
Thanks for your suggestions. So far i run test cases successfully with some of the errors but finally able to run test cases.
Now, i'm trying to generate the code coverage pdf but not done yet. Could you please help me out in this regard how should i generate this?
Used Simplecov gem and add below code in test helper.
```if ENV['COVERAGE'] == 'true'
  require 'simplecov'
  SimpleCov.start do
    add_filter ["/lib/patches"]
  end
  SimpleCov.start 'rails'
end```

Comment: Sorry, that's not something I can help with. You should create a new official question for that so others can help. Good luck!